# Диофантово уравнение, задача на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Диофантово** уравнение — 2
Даны числа a,b,c,d,e. Подсчитайте количество таких целых чисел от 0 до 1000, которые являются корнями уравнения (a∗x∗∗3+b∗x∗∗2+c∗x+d)/(x−e)=0, и выведите их количество.

**Входные данные**

Вводятся целые числа a,b,c,d,e, не превосходящие 30000 по абсолютному значению.

**Выходные данные**

**Выведите ответ на задачу.**

Мой код выдаёт ошибку, мол на ноль делить нельзя:

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
d=int(input())
e=int(input())
l=0
for i in range(1001):
    if (a*i**3+b*i**2+c*i+d)/(i-e)==0:
        l=l+1
print(l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если немного подумать?

Если нельзя делить на ноль, то нужно начинать не с нуля.

```
for i in range(1, 1001)
```

Comment: Подсчитайте количество таких целых чисел от 0 до 1000

Comment: Это ваша задача. Я вам исправил ошибку.  Считайте.

Comment: Если исправить мою ошибку так, как вы сказали, то программа будет выдавать неверный ответ.

Comment: Значит у вас неверный код. Эта ошибка не имеет отношения к тому, как вы считаете. Или вы думаете, что ее можно исправить по-другому, что ответ станет верным?

Comment: У вас же в коде совсем не та формула, что в задании!

Comment: Я исправила условие. Формула в коде правильная кроме i-e , но и это уже исправлено. Ошибка в другом.

Comment: Даже после исправления формула осталась неправильной.

Comment: Теперь правильно?

Comment: Неужели вы не видите, что скобки расставлены по-разному?

Comment: Я исправила.Но ошибка не в этом

Comment: Не в этом так не в этом. Ищите ошибку 

Comment: Если теперь в вопросе правильная формула, то мое решение разумеется не подходит. Вам нужно сравнивать i и e, и если они равны, то не проводить вычисление.

Comment: огромное спасибо!!

Answer (score 1):

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
d=int(input())
e=int(input())
l=0
for i in range(1001):
    if i!=e:
        if (a*i**3+b*i**2+c*i+d)/(i-e)==0:
            l=l+1
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для решения вашей задачи можно воспользоваться циклом while, и сразу написать, что i = 1. Выглядеть будет так: `while i <= 1001`: дальше ваш код, в конце i += 1. Если всё равно будет неверный ответ, тогда ваша формула неверна.

Comment: Здравствуйте, если вам не сложно, напишите задуманный вами код.

Comment: Это ничем не отличается от кода в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
d=int(input())
e=int(input())
i = 1
l = 0
while i <= 1001:
    if i!=e:
        if (a*i**3+b*i**2+c*i+d)/(i-e)==0:
            l += 1
    i += 1
print(l)
```

В общем, я всё исправил, если не работает, ошиблись вы в формуле, а в ней ищите ошибки самостоятельно, иначе обучение программированию смысла не имеет.